# How to give external javascript reference in cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am working on an application in which i need to take the parse *server time* and convert it into the *New York timezone* for which i am using `moment.js` and `moment-timezone.js`.

I am struggling with giving the reference to this *external js files in my cloud code*.

Comment: http://lillylabs.no/2014/04/12/handle-timezones-parse-com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require other files in your `cloud/` folder by adding that path:

```
require('cloud/myfile.js');
```

Typically, they are in the module format: http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1.1

myModule.js:

```
exports.add = function(a, b) { return a+b; }
```

main.js:

```
var myModule = require('cloud/myModule.js');

myModule.add(2, 2);
```

for moment, it should be:

```
var moment = require('cloud/moment.js');
var now = moment().format();
```

Comment: Fosco, the suggested answer did not worked for me. Please provide with any other alternative.

Comment: added an example for running moment.. moment is already a module, per http://momentjs.com/